# UIAlert action handler called only after another button is pressed?

Tags: ios, swift

I have a function that looks like this:

```
@IBAction func showAlert(){

//Some irrelevant code

let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Some Title", message: "Some Message", preferredStyle: .alert)

let action = UIAlertAction(title: "Close this alert", style: .default, handler: {
    action in
        self.startNewRound()
    })


alert.addAction(action)

present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)

}
```

Here is `updateLabels()`:

```
updateLabels() { 
targetLabel.text = String(targetValue)
scoreLabel.text = String(score)
roundLabel.text = String(round)
```

Here are some global variables:

```
var currentValue: Int = 0
@IBOutlet weak var targetLabel: UILabel!
var targetValue: Int = 0
@IBOutlet weak var scoreLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var roundLabel: UILabel!
var round: Int = 0
```

Here is startNewRound():

```
func startNewRound() {
targetValue = Int(arc4random_uniform(100)) + 1
currentValue = 50
slider.value = Float(currentValue)
round += 1
updateLabels()
}
```

The idea is that this function is called whenever a certain button in my main view controller is pressed, and then an alert pops up. Once the user closes the alert, `startNewRound()` is called.

However, with this current code, even though `startNewRound()` is called when the user closes the alert, and `startNewRound()` in turn calls `updateLabels()` which changes the text value of some labels, no change in the labels is visible until the user presses any other button. I have confirmed that lines both within `startNewRound()` and within `updateLabels()` (after the lines of code that change the value of the labels) are run correctly. All of my labels are properly connected in the view controller as outlets.

Edit: After running this program on a few different machines, I have confirmed that there is nothing wrong with my code. The machine I originally ran the project on was running on a poorly-installed virtual machine that ran very slowly. When run on other machines, the code runs well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can't reproduce. I created a test project with this code:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBAction func showAlert(){
        let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Some Title", message: "Some Message", preferredStyle: .alert)
        let action = UIAlertAction(title: "Close this alert", style: .default, handler: {
            action in
            self.startNewRound()
        })
        alert.addAction(action)
        present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
    func startNewRound() {
        print("start new round")
    }
}
```

I hooked up a button to the IBAction, and ran the project and tapped that button. The alert appeared. I tapped "Close This Alert". The words "start new round" appeared in the console immediately. No need to "press any other button first".

You can readily confirm this by doing what I did.

So if you are really having the behavior you describe, it is due to some cause completely outside the code that you showed.

---

In response to your comment, I changed the code to alter some labels in the interface:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var label1: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var label2: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var label3: UILabel!
    @IBAction func performButton(_ sender: Any) {
        self.showAlert()
    }
    func showAlert(){
        let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Some Title", message: "Some Message", preferredStyle: .alert)
        let action = UIAlertAction(title: "Close this alert", style: .default, handler: {
            action in
            self.startNewRound()
        })
        alert.addAction(action)
        present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
    func startNewRound() {
        self.label1.text = "hey"
        self.label2.text = "ha"
        self.label3.text = "ho"
    }
}
```

I tapped the button, the alert appeared, I dismissed it, and the label texts all changed.

Comment: I did the same thing as you, and you are correct - functions called in the action handler are being properly called. The issue is that while other functions, such as print statements, are called at the right time in `startNewRound()` and `updateLabels()`, for whatever reason the labels still don't update until another button is pressed.

I tested this by adding a print statement at the end of `updateLabels()` - it printed as soon as I closed the alert, but the labels hadn't updated yet even though the relevant lines were before the print statement.

Comment: I still can't reproduce. See my expanded answer. I've gone the extra mile here; it's up to you now to provide a project that reproduces the behavior you're seeing. I'll be glad to examine it.

Comment: I appreciate your help thus far. Here is a download link for the project: https://1fichier.com/?phm2hxgc1xdu27zqhj9d

Answer (score 0):

If you want to let to let `self.startNewRound()` to be called directly after presenting the alert view, you could call it in the `completion` of presenting it:

```
present(alert, animated: true) {
    self.startNewRound()
}
```

and -obviously-, remove it from the action handler. **Keep in mind** that the `completion` closure executes after the presentation finishes, which means it will be executed *before* even tapping the button.